# dlsym causing segfault when dynamically loading shm_open

Tags: c++, c, linux, dynamic-loading, dlsym

I am trying to figure out to load the function `shm_open` dynamically at runtime and have hit a wall.

My current code is as such:

**CMakeLists.txt**

```
project(dlsysm_stack_overflow_example)
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.16)

add_executable(${PROJECT_NAME}
    main.cpp
    custom_mman.cpp    
)

target_link_libraries(${PROJECT_NAME}
    dl
)
```

**custom_mman.cpp**

```cpp
#include <iostream>

#define _GNU_SOURCE 
#include <dlfcn.h>

extern "C"
{

int shm_open(const char* name, int oflag, mode_t mode)
{
    using ShmOpenFuncPtr_t = int (*)(const char*, int, mode_t);
    static ShmOpenFuncPtr_t real_shm_open = nullptr;

    std::cout << "custom shm_open\n";

    if (nullptr == real_shm_open)
    {
        real_shm_open = reinterpret_cast<ShmOpenFuncPtr_t>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "shm_open"));
        char* error = dlerror();
        if (error != nullptr) 
        {
            std::cout << "could not load shm_open at runtime! error: " << error << "\n";
            return -1;
        }
    }

    return real_shm_open(name, oflag, mode);
}

}
```

**main.cpp**

```cpp
#include <sys/mman.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <iostream>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    int return_value = shm_open("/shm_name", O_CREAT | O_RDWR, S_IRUSR | S_IWUSR);
    std::cout << "return_value: " << return_value << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

At the moment, because I give the executable the `custom_mann.cpp` source file, the linker finds my definition of `shm_open` before the standard library definition and calls that instead. My intention is then to do some logic before calling the real `shm_open` function.

However, the call to `dlsym` is returning a null pointer so when `real_shm_open` is called, a segfault occurs. Strangely, `dlerror` does not set the error code so the function doesn't return early as I would expect if `dlsym` is not returning the proper pointer.

Any ideas why this could be happening is much appreciated?

Answer (score 1):

`shm_open` is supplied by `librt.so`.  Per [the Linux `shm_open()` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/shm_open.3.html) (bolding mine):

> **NAME**
>
> shm_open, shm_unlink - create/open or unlink POSIX shared memory
> objects
>
> **SYNOPSIS**
>
> ```
>    #include <sys/mman.h>
>    #include <sys/stat.h>        /* For mode constants */
>    #include <fcntl.h>           /* For O_* constants */
>
>    int shm_open(const char *name, int oflag, mode_t mode);
>    int shm_unlink(const char *name);
> ```
>
> **Link with `-lrt`.**

You need to add `rt` to your `target_link_libraries`.

You should be checking the value returned from `dlsym()` directly for errors.  Per [the `dlsym` man page](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/dlsym.3.html):

> **RETURN VALUE**
>
> On success, these functions return the address associated with
> symbol.  On failure, they return NULL; the cause of the error can
> be diagnosed using dlerror(3).

Additionally, your code is not thread-safe:

```
static ShmOpenFuncPtr_t real_shm_open = nullptr;

std::cout << "custom shm_open\n";

if (nullptr == real_shm_open)
{
    real_shm_open = reinterpret_cast<ShmOpenFuncPtr_t>(dlsym(RTLD_NEXT, "shm_open"));
    char* error = dlerror();
    if (error != nullptr) 
    {
        std::cout << "could not load shm_open at runtime! error: " << error << "\n";
        return -1;
    }
}
```

Two or more threads can be executing the code in parallel, resulting in a corrupted `real_shm_open` that is neither `NULL` nor correct.

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I have linked rt and now I get the error message:

`could not load shm_open at runtime! error: (undefined symbol: shm_open)`

I am assuming this is because `dlsym` cannot find `librt.so` in all the locations it checks for. Do you know of any way around this without specifying an exact path to `librt.so` and using `dlopen` to obtain the handle.

Regarding the code not being thread-safe: you make a good point, however, I would not worry about it in this small example. When using this in my codebase, I will make sure to make it thread-safe.

Comment: *I am assuming this is because dlsym cannot find librt.so in all the locations it checks for.*  That is really strange.  `librt.so` is usually co-located with `libc.so`.  What does `ldd your_executable` show?  And `ldd -r your_executable`.  It should show a dependency on `librt.so`, but maybe the linker is omitting the dependency because your code isn't dependent on the library at link time.

Comment: `ldd` tells me that librt.so is not being linked. As you said, this is probably because it is not dependent at link time. I double checked and `librt.so` is definitely co-located with `libc.so`. I have, however, successfully managed to load `shm_open` with `dlsym` by obtaining a handle to `librt.so` with `dlopen` - would like to avoid this however. Do you think having an `init()` function at the start of `main()` which loads and stores pointer to `shm_open` in `librt.so` would suffice to force the linker not to remove the dependency?

Comment: *Do you think having an `init()` function at the start of `main()` which loads and stores pointer to `shm_open` in `librt.so` would suffice to force the linker not to remove the dependency?*  Probably not.  Using `dlsym()` in an `init()` function is no different than using it after `main()` is called.  A quick look at GNU `ld`'s man page indicates that perhaps `--no-as-needed` would work?